# In Flutter Tab bar, selected tab bar size and tab bar size can't align. How to align?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

Flutter tab bar, selected tab bar indicator and each tab size not equal. I use selected indicator with indicator decoration and wrap each tab inside container with PreferredSized. But can't align. How to align to equal with selected indicator and each container?

[This is my screen shot of the tab bar problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVcNv.png)

```
bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size(40, 40),
      child: Container(
        height: getScreenHeightRation(40.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFF0C185),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[600]),
        ),
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFD2A368),
          ),
          tabs: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))
              ),
              child: Tab(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/icon_ext/menu.png')),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))
              ),
              child: Tab(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/icon_ext/image.png')),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 150,
              child: Tab(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ImageIcon(
                        AssetImage('assets/images/icon_ext/placeholder.png')),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5.0,
                    ),
             
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
          controller: tabController,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue by flutter that is not fixed yet. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63700

For the time being, you can fix it by adding

```
labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
```

I also suggest to make the width of the containers match the size of the screen divided by the number of tabs instead of hard coding it. Not defining the width will also work

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
```

Comment: Adding label padding with work well to fit, although define container width or not. But only adding container width with screen ratio can't fit.